# Python class variable is shared with all instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-class

```
class list_class:
        def __init__(self, list_=[]):
                self.list_ = list_

        def add_item(self, item):
                self.list_ += [item]
```

```
>>> x = list_class()
>>> y = list_class()
>>> x.list_
[]
>>> y.list_
[]
>>> x.add_item(1)
>>> x.list_
[1]
>>> y.list_
[1]
```

Why does calling add_item() on x change the list_ variable on both instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `list_=[]` in a method argument is a bad Python idiom, for the reason you've discovered. Use the following instead:

```
class ListClass:
    def __init__(self, list_=None):
        if list_ is None:
            list_ = []
        self.list_ = list_

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.list_.append(item)
```

`list_` is set to `[]` when `__init__` is initially parsed. A list, however, is mutable, and not copied upon assignment. So when the `__init__` method is run, each time, it uses the same initial list. With the above replacement, `list_` is assigned to a *new* list every time `__init__` is run, and the problem is circumvented. The same holds for a dict as a default for function argument value. It doesn't matter if the list or dict are empty or contain values (`__init__(self, list_=[5])` would have had the same problem: don't use a mutable variable in a function argument as a default value.

See [the warning in the tutorial section of default function arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).

Other more Pythonic idioms are using CamelCase for class names, and using `somelist.append(item)` instead of `somelist += [item]`.

Comment: Can't tell you how long I was debugging this issue, thank you for the details

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this a few times but can't remember the ultimate reason. The solution is to not (or ever) declare empty iterables in your functions/classes.

```
class List_Class:
    def __init__(self, list_):
        self.list_ = list_

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.list_ += [item]


x = List_Class(list())
y = List_Class(list())
print(x.list_)
print(y.list_)
x.add_item(1)
print(x.list_)
print(y.list_)
```

Comment: "The solution is to not (or ever) declare empty iterables in your functions/classes": you can set a function argument to a default value of `''` just fine, and a string is iterable. And using `list_=[5]` (non-empty iterable) will have the same problem as that of an empty list.